# Is Phoenix's scrub_params like Rails strong parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

The documentation for the Phoenix `scrub_params` method is a little unclear to me.  It seems like this functionality is similar to the Rails strong parameters feature.  However, when you use it in a controller like so,

```
plug :scrub_params, "user" when action in [:create]
```

... you're not explicitly stating which parameters you want to whitelist.  I've looked at the code for `scrub_params`, but I'm noobish enough with Elixir that I'm not quite sure what's going on.

Is this method just looking at the model and using the required and optional field module attributes for whitelisting parameters?

Also, the `scrub_params` documentation says it "Checks to see if the required_key is present".  What is the "required key"?  Is that just the required fields from the model?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The [scrub_params/2](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Controller.html#scrub_params/2) function is not really like Rails strong parameters. In Ecto you define the permitted key in your changeset function using [Ecto.Changeset.cast/4](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#cast/4).

Scrub parameters does the following:

- Ensure the required key exists.
- Change empty values from the map in params with the required key to `nil`

For example, calling:

```
plug scrub_params "user"
```

Will check for the presence of a "user" key. From [the docs](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Controller.html#scrub_params/2):

> If the required_key is not present, it will raise Phoenix.MissingParamError.

If you have a params map which looks like:

```
%{"user" => %{"name" => "foo", "age" => ""}}
```

Then the "age" parameter would be converted to `nil`. This allows you to call your changeset function directly with the params:

```
def create(conn, %{"user" => user_params}) do
  User.changeset(user_params)
end
```

The `scrub_params/2` is completely unrelated to your model, it just works well with Ecto since the `Ecto.Changeset.cast/4` function takes a set of required fields and a set of optional fields. Passing `nil` to a required field will invalidate the changeset and add an error for the field.

Comment: Thanks for clarification.  That makes sense.

Comment: So what's the equivalent of strong params in Phoenix? I need to restrict user input. Appreciate an answer [to my question here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39938824/elixir-phoenix-restrict-params-like-rails-strong-params) Thanks.