# Convert empty strings to nil before saving

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have the following `User` model and want to make sure that nobody stores empty strings (e.g. a space) in the database. If somebody enters "   " (multiple spaces) for `first_name`, `last_name` or `nickname` that attribute should be saved with the value `nil`. In Rails I would tackle that with a `before_validation` callback. What's the best way to solve this in Phoenix?

```elixir
defmodule MyApp.User do
  use MyApp.Web, :model

  schema "users" do
    field :first_name, :string
    field :last_name, :string
    field :nickname, :string

    timestamps
  end

  @required_fields ~w()
  @optional_fields ~w(first_name last_name nickname)

  @doc """
  Creates a changeset based on the `model` and `params`.

  If no params are provided, an invalid changeset is returned
  with no validation performed.
  """
  def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
    model
    |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you using `plug :scrub_params, "user", ...` in `UserController`?

Comment: Yes, I do. aaaahhh... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33975229/is-phoenixs-scrub-params-like-rails-strong-parameters
Thank you!

Comment: @Dogbert Could you please post it as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The recommended way is to handle this in the controller using the [`scrub_params`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Controller.html#scrub_params/2) plug which recursively converts empty strings (including those consisting only of spaces) into `nil`s for a given key.

Phoenix generators insert the following code in the generated controller (if the controller is named `UserController`):

```
plug :scrub_params, "user" when action in [:create, :update]
```

You could use something similar.