# Elixir/Phoenix restrict params like Rails strong params

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am making an API only Phoenix app. I come from a Ruby on Rails background, so bear with me.

Say I have a User model with `email`, `password`, `password_hash`, and `role` fields.

I need to restrict the `role` and `password_hash` fields from user input, or whitelist the `email` and `password` fields. Right now anyone could POST this sign up as an admin:

```
{
    "user": {
        "email": "test3@test.com",
        "password": "testpw",
        "password_hash": "shouldn't allow user input",
        "role": "admin"
    }
}
```

This is typically accomplished in Rails using strong params, which will strip out fields that are not explicitly specified.

**How do I do restrict/whitelist params with Phoenix using best practices?**

This is my create method in my user_controller:

```
  def create(conn, %{"user" => user_params}) do
    changeset = User.registration_changeset(%User{}, user_params)
    ...
    ...
  end
```

And here is my schema and changesets in the model, user.ex. I'm following [this tutorial, it says "we pipe the new changeset through our original one"](https://medium.com/@Stephanbv/elixir-phoenix-lets-code-authentication-todo-application-part-2-f52348c2b32f#.c8ni3p2uq)

```
  schema "users" do
    field :email, :string
    field :password, :string, virtual: true
    field :password_hash, :string
    field :role, :string

    timestamps()
  end

  def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
    model
    |> cast(params, ~w(email), [])
    |> downcase_email()
    |> unique_constraint(:email)
    |> validate_format(:email, ~r/@/)
  end

  def registration_changeset(model, params) do
    model
    |> changeset(params)
    |> cast(params, ~w(password), [])
    |> validate_length(:password, min: 6)
    |> put_password_hash()
  end
```

Phoenix's [scrub_params is close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33975229/is-phoenixs-scrub-params-like-rails-strong-parameters), but it doesn't sound like what I need.

I think I can accomplish this by pattern matching but I'm not sure how.

Comment: It's odd that `cast` is not working, because it should do exactly what you're asking: only allowing the `email` parameter. Also, your controller is using `User.registration_changeset/2`, but you're showing us the code for `User.changeset/2`.

Comment: What does your `registration_changeset` look like? Your `changeset` should already be ignoring the `role` field in `params`.

Comment: I would also recommend to use [`cast/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#cast/3) over `cast/4`, as the latter is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, @tompave , I've amended my question with the registration_changeset. It's definitely allowing at least the role field to go through and be saved. Also, I added the role field using a separate migration but that shouldn't make a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the code behaves as expected and does not save the role field. (I was reading the request in the console instead of actually checking the database.)

Comment: Thanks for reporting back. You should either update the question (so that people searching for a similar problem can find the info more easily) or close it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late here but here is this approach:

```
defmodule MyApp.Utils do
  def strong_params(params, allowed_fields) when is_map(params) do
    allowed_strings = Enum.map(allowed_fields, &Atom.to_string(&1))

    Enum.reduce(params, [], fn {k, v}, acc ->
      key = check_key(k, allowed_strings)
      acc ++ [{key, v}]
    end)
    |> Enum.reject(fn {k, _v} -> k == nil end)
    |> Map.new()
  end

  defp check_key(k, allowed_strings) when is_atom(k) do
    str_key = Atom.to_string(k)

    if str_key in allowed_strings do
      k
    end
  end
  defp check_key(k, allowed_strings) when is_binary(k) do
    if k in allowed_strings do
      String.to_existing_atom(k)
    end
  end
  defp check_key(_, _), do: nil
end
```

[image]

> Reference:
>   https://medium.com/@alves.lcs/phoenix-strong-params-9db4bd9f56d8