# Ecto filter empty record

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have an embedded association with two models User and Address, and I connect them like this:

```
defmodule App.Address do
  # ...

  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [:address, :city])
  end
end
```

when I use:

```
 inputs_for :addresses, [append: [App.Address{}]], fn address ->
   text_input address, :address, class: ""
 end
```

and I enter empty data, it gets saved as nil, I'm hoping for a solution to filter out empty data and prevent them from getting saved, all I came up with is using Enum.filter in the controller wich gets ugly as I think:

```
...
filtered_addresses = Enum.filter(user_params["addresses"], fn {x, map} ->
  map.address != "" and map.city != ""
end)

user_params = Map.put(user_params, :addresses, filtered_addresses)
```

is there is a more cleaner way using the model validations, or a cleaner way in the controller ?

Comment: I think function [cast_embed/3](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#cast_embed/3) should accept one more option like `:reject_if` by analogy with rails [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html). I've posted [question to elixir-ecto mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elixir-ecto/ScPo16tfllc)

Comment: @OleksandrAvoyants That is the point of the `:with` option. You specify a changeset that can reject it if it is invalid.

Comment: @JustinWood Please correct me if I'm wrong but I think currently there is no way for changeset to reject the record.

Comment: _Sidenote_: [José Valim uses](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2016/12/many-to-many-and-upserts/?utm_source=elixir-status&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=blog-post-promotion) explicit `|> Enum.reject(& &1 == "")` for the nearly same task.

Comment: @mudasobwa Yes this makes sense, this is a concise solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want validations on the changeset. Something along the lines of

```
def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
  struct
  |> cast(params, [:address, :city])
  |> validate_required([:address, :city])
end
```

This will make sure there is data in the columns `address` and `city`. If there is not, the record will not be saved.

You can read more about validations and constraints [in the docs](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#module-validations-and-constraints)

Comment: Thanks Justin for your answer, the addresses does not have to be required. When an address field is not set, nothing saved into the db, without raising an error.

Comment: This doesn't raise an error unless you are using `insert!/2`. If you use `insert/2` it will return either `{:ok, struct}` or `{:error, changeset}`. Nothing is raised, it just returns a value and you can do what you want with it.

Comment: Yes, but it still have to validate the User model, so it needs to be able to catch the errors of that model (User)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question properly, you might be looking for [`Phoenix.Controller.scrub_params/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Controller.html#scrub_params/2).

From the documentation linked above:

> This function is useful to remove empty strings sent via HTML forms.

Also, [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39938824/elixir-phoenix-restrict-params-like-rails-strong-params) seems to be similar to your question, but the goal is the opposite. Linking it here for the sake of hypertext.

Comment: Wouldn't this still lead to `nil` being placed in the database?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Justin is right, the scrub_params in this case will just check if the "address" key is present, not to validate the address map (wich contains :address and :city)

Comment: I was under an impression that `nil`s won’t be saved into the database by Ecto by default, while empty strings will.